# adding a random color to a generated line

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, colors, generator

I am beginning to learn javascript and i want to add a random color to each random line that gets generated in this project...

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(c);
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
var position = 0;

ctx.lineWidth = window.prompt("what line width do you want?","0.5");

ctx.color = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);

function animateCircle(position) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    ctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height/2,(c.width > c.height ? c.height : c.width)/3,position,position+Math.random()*10,false);ctx.stroke();
}
window.setInterval(function() {
    animateCircle(position);
    position += 3;
}, 10);
```

I wanted it to make it so that every generated line was a different random color every time so i tried using the ctx.color but it doesn't seem to apply to the generated lines but instead just stay default color black. It looks like it is skipping over it totally. And when I print it the script doesn't even seem to start...
but my ctx.color doesn't work and i don't understand why..
Please help 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strokeStyle` instead of color. There are a couple of other issues you will notice as well which I point out below:

```
function animateCircle(position) {

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

    /// remember beginPath() here or the arc will accumulate
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height/2,(c.width > c.height ? c.height : c.width)/3,position,position+Math.random()*10,false);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

To draw a line, use this instead of the `arc()`:

```
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);  /// replace x and y with your positions
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
ctx.stroke();
```

Increase the interval to at least 16ms

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    animateCircle(position);
    position += 3;
}, 16);
```

or preferably use `requestAnimtionFrame` for smoother animations:

```
(function loop() {
    animateCircle(position);
    position += 3;
    requestAnimtionFrame(loop);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `strokeStyle`, not `color`. Try:

```
function animateCircle(position) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
    ctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height/2,(c.width > c.height ? c.height : c.width)/3,position,position+Math.random()*10,false);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

You will have an unexpected result (that I let you discover), but it should help you understand a bit more about canvas :)

Comment: thanks a lot this is a really cool effect!! :) it is doing that insane psychedelic effect on the whole object and changing colors :D
but it doesn't accomplish what I intended it to do :)
I wanted it to draw a line in any color every time so I would end up with lots of different colors bunched up! but I do have to say sir that this is really cool!!! and thanks again